# Unable to cast System.Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal CustomPrincipal in MVC5

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

I am trying to implement a custom principal in an MVC5 app. To start I have tried to just implement IPrincipal and also override the base WebViewPage. However, the cast from to the customPrincipal is not working. I am getting :

> **Unable to cast object of type 'System.Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal' to type
>   CustomPrincipal**.

I cannot understand why this will not cast and want to make sure at least this works before I go down the path of implementing everything I need in the customPrincipal. Why is this unable to cast?

```
public abstract class CustomWebViewPage : WebViewPage
{
    public virtual new CustomPrincipal User { get { return (CustomPrincipal)base.User; } }
}

public abstract class CustomWebViewPage<TModel> : WebViewPage<TModel>
{
    public virtual new CustomPrincipal User { get { return (CustomPrincipal)base.User; } }
}


public class CustomPrincipal : IPrincipal
{
    public bool IsInRole(string role)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public IIdentity Identity { get; private set; }
}
```

Comment: Because you need to set the value of `User` to your `CustomPrincipal` (usually in the `protected void Application_PostAuthenticateRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)` method of `Global.asax.cs`)